# TeXstudio 2.12, Ubuntu 20.04: changing the displayed name of the window

Tags: texstudio

Currently the TeXstudio window's name is /home/foo/bar.tex - TeXstudio, which gets abbreviated to /home/foo... on the task bar; this I find quite annoying, since it is very non-descriptive.

Is there a way of changing the way TeXstudio names its window? Ideally I would like the window to be called bar.tex - TeXstudio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the code below as update_window_title_v1.0.py, make it executable and run it in the background:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

"""
Rename X11 windows if they have too long names

Written by Z J Laczik

Modify the following defines to fine tune behaviour :
src_pattern = r"/.+/"
replacement = "/.../"
limit = 16
period = 2

N.B. Be careful modifying src_pattern and replacement!
Wrong choice may result in the modification of all window names, 
setting window names to '', or ending up with infinitely long
window names ptoentially crashing your window manager.

Change log

Date: 20220609  Version: 1.0
    First release
"""

import time
import re
from Xlib import display

# change debug to True to enable debug messages
debug = False
# debug = True

def get_window_name( window ) :
    # try and get utf-8 window name first, if that fails, try and get legacy name
    for ( atom, prop_type ) in ( ( NET_WM_NAME, UTF8_STRING), ( WM_NAME, STRING ) ) :
        try :
            prop = window.get_full_property( atom, prop_type )
        except UnicodeDecodeError :
            window_name = "<could not decode characters>"
        else :
            # check whether get_full_property was succesful
            # if not, set default name and try next atom
            if prop :
                # extract value data from property object
                window_name = prop.value
                # at this point window_name should be a string or a byte array
                # it it is bytes then convert to string
                if isinstance( window_name, bytes ) :
                    if ( atom == NET_WM_NAME ) :
                        # decode bytes as UTF-8
                        window_name = window_name.decode( 'utf-8', 'replace' )
                    else :
                        # decode bytes as ASCII
                        window_name = window_name.decode( 'ascii', 'replace' )
                return window_name
            else :
                # set default return value
                window_name = "<unnamed window>"
    # we should only get here if neither atoms worked, hence return default
    return window_name

def set_window_name( window, name ) :
    try :
        # set UTF-8 window name
        window.change_property( NET_WM_NAME, UTF8_STRING, 8, name.encode( 'utf-8', 'replace' ) )
        # set legacy ASCII name
        window.change_property( WM_NAME, STRING, 8, name.encode( 'ascii', 'replace' ) )
    except :
        pass

def check( window, src_pattern = r"/.+/", replacement = "/.../", limit = 16 ) :
    # get list of child windows
    window_list = window.query_tree().children
    # check each child window
    for window in window_list :
        # get current window name
        old_name = get_window_name( window )
        # check if length is above limit and if it matches replacement regex
        if ( len( old_name ) > limit ) :
            ( new_name, matches ) = re.subn( src_pattern, replacement, old_name );
            if ( matches > 0 and new_name != old_name ) :
                set_window_name( window, new_name )
                if debug :
                    print( "> Replaced '%s' with '%s'" % ( old_name, new_name ) )
        # recursively check child windows below current window
        check( window, src_pattern, replacement, limit )

# get display and root window
dsp = display.Display()
root_window = dsp.screen().root
# get various atoms
UTF8_STRING = dsp.get_atom( 'UTF8_STRING' )     # property type utf-8
STRING = dsp.get_atom( 'STRING' )               # property type string
NET_WM_NAME = dsp.get_atom( '_NET_WM_NAME' )    # utf-8 encoded window name
WM_NAME = dsp.get_atom( 'WM_NAME' )             # legacy ascii encoded window name

# define regex pattern to use for window name matching
src_pattern = r"/.+/"
# define replacement string
replacement = "/.../"
# length limit, replace window name only if longer than limit
limit = 16
# repeat check every 'period' seconds
period = 2

# start main loop checking all window names and
# changing them if there is a match and they are too long
while True :
    # check() starts with the root window and then recursively traverses all child windows
    check( root_window, src_pattern, replacement, limit )
    # wait until next check
    time.sleep( period )
```

[Link to .py file](https://blog.laczik.org/change-x11-window-title/)

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks!